# Spearman rank after Pearson chi-square

Tags: chi-squared-test, post-hoc, spearman-rho

I'm considering to use the Pearson chi-square test to see if two categorical variables are significantly associated. If the association is significant I want to apply the Spearman rank test to see if the association is monotonic.

I wonder if this is a common approach, because i couldn't find any scientific paper applying both tests to the same data. Do I have control for multiple testing when I'm using Spearman rank as "post hoc"?

Comment: How would you order categorical variables? For instance, putting aside your personal preferences about pets, is $\text{dog} > \text{cat}?$

Comment: i have ordered variables, e.g. qualifications (undergraduate< postgraduate < specialist)